# Does there exist an FPTAS for bin packing problem?

Tags: optimization, np-complete, np-hard, approximation, polynomial-time-reductions

We know that there does not exist an FPTAS for the bin packing problem because it is a strongly NP-HARD problem, as the 3-partitioning problem which is strongly np-hard, can be reduced to the bin packing problem. Moreover, by corollary 8.6 of Vazirani's approximation algorithms book, there is no FPTAS for strongly NP-hard problems. However, please notice problem 9.8 of the approximation algorithms book by Dr. Vazirani in the bin packing chapter:
"Show that if there is an algorithm for bin packing having a guarantee of OPT(I) + log^2(OPT(I)), then there is a fully polynomial approximation scheme for this problem."

Moreover, Please notice to the chapter notes at the end of the bin packing chapter in the same book:
"An improved algorithm, having a guarantee of OPT(I) + log^2(OPT(I)), was given by Karmarkar and Karp [163]."

These 2 statements imply that there exists an FPTAS for bin packing. Is not it a paradox? Which one is true?